# What is the fastest way to do bulk assignments into NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a machine learning problem, and I need to construct an array of dimensions `m x n x p`.

For the sake of the question, let's say we have `m` locations, `n` time windows, and `p` features for each observation at each time window.

Our data store can only return one location worth of data at a time, in other words we get an array of size `1 x n x p` back. But for the prediction step, we want everything consolidated into a single array of size `m x n x p`.

With relatively small `p`, this is fast enough using the naïve approach the we don't care. In some cases, however, we have fairly large `p`, and that's made this fairly slow.

For example:

```
In [44]: A = np.arange(4800000000, dtype=np.float32).reshape(20,30,8000000)

In [45]: x = np.random.randn(30, 8000000)

In [46]: %timeit A[0,:] = x
39.5 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

While 40ms is not a lot on face, doing that for an `m` of 100 results in 4 seconds on this one fairly straightforward operation.

Is there a faster way to do this array construction?

Comment: No, there is no faster way.

Comment: to be honest that's as fast as your memory can physically go ... so a sort of solution is to get faster memories or get them to work in dual channel mode ... but this is not guaranteed to get anything faster ... but if you are transfering the data to a gpu, you can aynchronously transfer the data part by part instead of waiting for the data to be complete in the RAM .

Comment: @AhmedAEK yeah, and it's pretty fast. each individual assignment is taking less than a nanosecond

Comment: Like, a lot less, about 800 femtoseconds (slightly less than a picosecond!)

Comment: You succeed to reach 45 GiB/s throughput which is already pretty good (unless you work on a high-performance server). Wait: 388 billion bits/s. This is I am frequently dizzy by the insane amount of resource consumed by people doing machine learning stuff. Please consider reducing the amount of data first. Working on dozens of GiB in memory is certainly not reasonable. If you want a fast code you should operate in the L3 cache. Memory is not gonna be much faster any time soon because of the Memory Wall.